# Flask SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many relationship: no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created an association table (event_company) for two models (Company & Events).  If I try to append the Events.id to this table, I get the error `no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`.  I have read some other posts saying

> error means that an integer is being interpreted as an ORM object

However, how can I then add the id to the association table?

**UPDATE**

In my forms, I have used a dropdown to get the Event information and then I access this in the Views by using `events_list = form.events_id.data`.
I get the model object by querying:  `the_event = Events.query.filter_by(id=events_list.id).first()`

I then try to append to the association table (Event_company) by using `company_info.event_id.append(the_event)` and it is successful.

However, when I look at the information in the Company.event_id, it is showing me the **repr** function and not the Event.id.

**company_info** is the session adding my company info to the database, and **event_id** is the field in company to which I want to append that id of the Events model.

Thank you for your help!

**Models.py**

```
# This is the association table
event_company = db.Table('event_company',
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
)

I HAVE REMOVED SOME EXTRA FIELDS IN BOTH COMPANY & EVENTS MODELS

class Company(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_id = db.relationship('Events', secondary=event_company, backref='event', lazy='select')
    REMOVED FIELDS FOR EASIER READING


class Events(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    REMOVED FIELDS FOR EASIER READING
```

**View.py**

```
class RegisterView(MethodView):

    template_file = 'buyers/register.html'
    form_class = RegistrationForm

    def get(self):
        return render_template(self.template_file, form=self.form_class())

    def post(self):
        form = self.form_class()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            events_list = form.events_id.data
            company_info = Company(
                email=form.email.data
            )
            db.session.add(company_info)
            db.session.commit()

            # Adding to the association database
            company_info.event_id.append(events_list.id)
            db.session.commit
            
            flash("Thank you for registering.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        return render_template(self.template_file, form=form)
```

Comment: After more research, I am realizing that I need to represent the entire ORM and not just an integer like I did above `company_info.event_id.append(events_list.id)`.  However, even if I add the entire Event `the_event = Events.query.filter_by(id=events_list.id).first()`, it does add it but doesn't add the Events.id, and this is what I need.

Comment: Ok, I think this is all correct and it is working.  I just didn't understand how to access the information correctly.  I just need to query the correct column of the model that I need.